# Ionic 2 FileTransferError: All response params are null; using livereload with android device

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying to send a file along with other request params to my backend service using the FileTransfer native plugin. However, when I run the file transfer request, the response is a FileTransferError and each of the params is null. Here is my method:

```
    mediaUpload(product) {
    console.log(this.picture);
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileName: this.title,
        headers: {},
        params: {
            productId: product.id,
            imageTitle: this.title,
        }
    };

    fileTransfer.upload(this.picture, this.createImageURL)
        .then((data) => {
            // success
            console.log(data);
            this.loader.dismiss();
            if (data.response === "false") {
                alert('Media upload failed!');
            }
            else {
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
            }

        }, (err) => {
            // error
            alert("Network error with image upload. Please try again later!");
            console.log(err);
            this.loader.dismiss();
        });

}
```

Comment: Did you check for any async errors ?

Comment: The only error I get is a FileTransferError and all the response params are null from the request